# how to find and replace a word in a mysql column?

Tags: mysql, sql, string

I have a column containing list of streets. I need to replace 'street' with 'St'. The replacement can be made in the current column or in a new column with the address in the required format. The following is the sample data. 'Column 1' contains the data in current format. 'Column 2' contains the data in the desired format.

```
Column 1         Column 2
Hillary Street   Hillary St
Golf Road        Golf Road
Oldwood Street   Oldwood St
```

How do I do this?

Edit:

This query works for this:

```
UPDATE table SET column = REPLACE(column, 'Street', 'St');
```

Is it possible to set a rule to this column. Such that all data added to this get formatted this way automatically? Or I need to repeat this query each time?

Comment: Ever consider looking at the [MySQL string function documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html)?  Because this is a trivial question...

Comment: @ OMG Ponies I did have a look at it but 'SELECT REPLACE('www.mysql.com', 'w', 'Ww');' didn't help me. I couldn't figure out the 'update' and 'set' part of it. I'm a beginner in MySQL. I'll probably do some learning and then start asking questions here in future.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Run a query like this to update in the **same** column:

```
UPDATE table 
   SET column = REPLACE(column, 'Street', 'St');
```

Comment: You may want to add a smarter regex to that. Otherwise "first st" = "firstreet street".  Also, best to make a backup of this column first.

Comment: @Chris Henry - if you run `REPLACE("first st", 'Street', 'St')` do you get `firststreet street`?  I think you have it backwards...

Answer (score 3):

So, if i understand correctly, you want to modify the data on the database based on wether or not you're using the word street. I think this is the call u need.

```
update [table_name] set [field_name] = replace([field_name],'[string_to_find]','[string_to_replace]');
```

I think this is the method you need to use, so your ending code will look something like

```
update myTable set address = replace(address,'street','St');
```

Is this what you meant?

Comment: Yes. Is it possible to set a rule for the table such that all data that is added to the table are also formatted this way automatically?

Comment: @Shyam Natraj Kanagasabapathy - you could use triggers to reformat inserted and updated values