# Trying to search a column in a db (sqlite) and replace specific numeric values with nothing

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to search the table `actions` in my database and delete any value within the `code` column that has the value of `40`.

I have tried:

```
REPLACE (code,40,'') 
FROM actions
```

but no luck.  Also tried the `DELETE` function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to find and replace a word in a mysql column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171512/how-to-find-and-replace-a-word-in-a-mysql-column)

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for `UPDATE`:

```
Update   actions
Set      code = Null
Where    code = 40
```

If you need to delete the entire row, you can do it with the following:

```
Delete   
From     actions
Where    code = 40
```

Comment: When I tried that I get the following error message:

Comment: NOT NULL constraint failed: actions.code: Update   actions
Set      code = Null
Where    code = 40

Comment: You have a `NOT NULL` constraint on your column that you're trying to set to `NULL`.  You will either need to update the column definition, or set the value to something other than `NULL` (i.e. `0` or `-1` - this depends on your data and how you use it.)

Comment: Problem though!  I just found out that I need to delete any row instead of deleting the the cell content where that data shows up.  How can i do that?

Comment: @ImpactGary Updated answer for the `DELETE` script.

Comment: I would ***HIGHLY*** recommend putting this in a `TRANSACTION` before running it, then verifying that you get what you need before you `COMMIT` it. It's a whole lot easier to `ROLLBACK` than it is to restore from a backup.

Comment: Thank you for your help, that works perfectly!  If I want to add multiple code values to look for and delete the rows they are contained in, would I place multiple numbers separated by parenthesis like this: Where    code = 40,41,69,32?

Comment: For that, you need to do `Where code In (40, 41, 69, 32)`

Comment: Or could I rather just repeat the SQL statement over and over again?

Comment: So I could comment out numbers if I want to?

Comment: I Thank You so much for your help with this!